# Null value of foreign key column in Django Serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using `ModelSerializer` and setting all fields from my `Item` model, but I have `null` value in `category` field when retrieving everything. [Item description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRUKX.png)

[Item and Category Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEjlK.png)

[As you can see value of category is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc08S.png)

Comment: Please post your code in here rather than including screenshots. It's much easier to answer questions that include actual code.

Comment: The `category` field of the `Item` model allows the `null` values, so that relationship hasn't been set. Link the `Item` objects to a `Category` and that won't be `null`.

Comment: but i already did that

Comment: I already linked the Item with Category. It shows category_id when i write "category_id" in serializer, but it shows me null when i write "____all____". The problem here is "category". It does not link with this keyword.

Comment: What about if you add a depth to the serializer? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization